# applied before after on various div, now those content overflowing my header

Tags: html, css

I have a header. it was fixed. but after working on a div where I put "before" to insert a overlay background color, then I see that those overlay's content overflow my header. Please help me.

I tried giving z index on header, position relative, absolute but nothing worked.

Comment: Without your (relevant) "*[mcve]*" HTML and CSS, how did you expect us to offer any advice? Please, all we know of your situation is what you present in your question. If you give us none of the information, we can't offer any useful help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.